# How to change the true state of a checkbox to an icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, state

I was making a login screen for a website (subject: vintage lights)  and wanted a checkbox. But I thought it would be interesting if the true state of the checkbox were to be an icon of a lightbulb. Is this possible in any or other way?[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l1rq.jpg this is my code of the form/checkbox:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <input class="customCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="rememberMe">
    <label for="rememberMe">Remember Me</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<input id="trigger" type="checkbox">
<label for="trigger" class="checker"></label>
```

```
#trigger {
  display: none;
}

.checker {
  background-image: url("https://p.bigstockphoto.com/GeFvQkBbSLaMdpKXF1Zv_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Blue-Lakes-And--227291596.jpg");
  background-position: left center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 20px;
}

#trigger:checked + .checker {
    background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg");
}
```

So when the user clicks the checkbox the background changes. Of course it's just the rough example but I think you get the idea.